# Http Handler not intercepting .html and .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, httphandler

I have SPA using angular(routing too is with angular).I have written http handler which will intercept old url and redirect to new url.

When I give path as * its hitting but with *.html not hitting my handler.
Please find code snip.

My Handler code-

```
public class PageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            HttpRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpResponse response = context.Response;
            string newUrl=string.Empty;
            if (Convert.ToString(request.Path) != null)
                 newUrl = GetNewURL(Convert.ToString(request.Path));
            if (newUrl != string.Empty)
                response.Redirect(newUrl);
            else
                response.Redirect("/404");
        }
}
```

Webconfig setting-

```
 <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add verb="*" path="*.html,*.aspx" name="myHandler" type="LucidFox.Helpers.PageHandler"/>
 </handlers>
```

Not sure why its not intercepting .aspx and .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS 7's handler mapping is different than IIS 6's handler mapping. In IIS 6, you can map your handlers like this in web.config.It allows you to use multiple paths, comma-delimited.

```
<handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add verb="*" path="*.html,*.aspx" name="myHandler" type="LucidFox.Helpers.PageHandler"/>
 </handlers>
```

In IIS 7, it's in a different section.It doesn't support multiple paths, so you need to map your handler for each path.

```
  <handlers>
   <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
   <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
   <add verb="*" path="*.html" name="myHandler" type="LucidFox.Helpers.PageHandler"/>
   <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" name="myHandler" type="LucidFox.Helpers.PageHandler"/>
 </handlers>
```